# How to display simple images instead of configurable images when submitting a transactional emails

Tags: php, magento

When I send a transactional email I get both the configurable image and the simple image I only need the simple image

This is the bit of code I am modifying item.phtml

getAllItems() as $_item): ?>getChildItem()) break; else $i++;

```
?>
<tbody>


    <tr <?php echo $i%2?'bgcolor="#FFFFFF"':'' ?>>
        <!--PRODUCT Name-->
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:3px 9px">- <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></td>
        <!--PRODUCT SKU-->
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px;"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getSku($_item)) ?></td>
        <!--PRODUCT IMAGE-->
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px;">
            <?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())
            ->load($_item->getProductId()); ?>
            <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(75); ?>" width="75" alt="" />
        </td>
```

Anything would help at this point

Answer (score 0):

hello please just change

```
getAllItems() changes to getAllVisiableItems()
```

then in item modify code

```
  <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:3px 9px">- <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></td>
        <!--PRODUCT SKU-->
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px;"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getSku($_item)) ?></td>
        <!--PRODUCT IMAGE-->
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px;">
            <?php 
         $sku=$item->getSku();
            $productid = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                                  ->getIdBySku(trim($sku));

            // Initiate product model
            $childproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId());

            // Load specific product whose tier price want to update
            $childproduct ->load($productid);

                <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($childproduct , 'image')->resize(75); ?>" width="75" alt="" />
</td>
```

Comment: I am not sure exactly where I need to put this

Comment: i  have edit ,please check.Let me if you have any query